# Why say "current is flowing" (as opposed to, say, "charge is flowing")?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, electric-current, charge

From what I read from books and website CURRENT is the "rate of flow of electric charges". So its should be the electric charges that flow in the conductor. Then why many sources state that "current is flowing"? Like we will say "water is flowing" not "the rate of water flow" is flowing.

Comment: probably just to emphasis current is not null

Comment: Because language is not physics. Pedantically, it would be appropriate to say charges are flowing. But, we commonly use voltage and current to describe circuits, so we short circuit the current -> charges moving -> current flowing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about nomenclature rather than physics.

Comment: You are very right in all you write. This term is indeed inconsistent in language. You often hear the terms "current" and "current flow" as the same thing and saying that "there is a current" and "charge is flowing" has become equivalent with "current is flowing". Inconsistent language, but that is not uncommon.

Comment: @SebastianRiese physics nomenclature?

Answer (score 1):

Current is a flow of electric charge just like water flow or air flow is the mass or volume flow of water or air.  The rate of flow for current is charge per unit time. The rate of flow of water is given by mass or volume per time.
Added later:
In the end this question is **not a physical question** because it relates to common language usage. Both the expression "charge is flowing" and "current is flowing" is frequently used and there is usually no doubt about what is meant by that. You can also say that the water is flowing and that the river is flowing and the water current is flowing. Everybody knows what it means.

Comment: So the answer to the question is...?